# InvalidUserName error when try to add new namespace to ServiceBus using powershell remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, azureservicebus

We have local installation of AzurePack: ServiceBus 1.1 (wpi alias ServiceBus_1_1)

We need to add new namespace to ServiceBus on application deployment.

Here is code that I try to execute from one server:

```ps
Invoke-Command -ComputerName some-remote-server -Verbose -ScriptBlock { New-SBNamespace -Name new-sb-namespace -ManageUsers {domain}\{user} }
```

Here is a response that I receive:

```ps
The user name '{domain}\{user}' is invalid.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (vgl:String) [New-SBNamespace], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidUserName,Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.NewSBNamespaceCommand
+ PSComputerName        : some-remote-server
```

I can execute `New-SBNamespace -Name new-sb-namespace -ManageUsers {domain}\{user}` locally on remote server without any problems

I have tried different combinations of domain/user, different accounts.
I can't find any information about why I receive this error.

Same error I'm getting when use `Enter-PSSession` command and execute `New-SBNamespace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.
Using `-Authentication Credssp -Credential $credentials` have solved issue, but caused a need to supply those credentials in script.

Comment: Man, you just saved us! :) We use slightly different scenario, and this particular error wasn't the only weird things we faced. In the end, when we had dealt with the rest of them, this issue was bothering us. The tiny `-Authentication Credssp` parameter did a trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName some-remote-server -Verbose -ScriptBlock { New-SBNamespace -Name new-sb-namespace -ManageUsers {user}@{domain}
```

So the notation of users/groups should be user@domain

Hope this helps

Comment: No it's not working =( I will try to do this via REST api. But it's very ugly solution to use from powershell